# Где поставить ударение?

Tags: орфоэпия

Во фразе «у этой медали есть две стороны» где ставится ударение в слове «стороны»?

Answer (score 2):

Чего у неё две? Сторон**ы́** (родительный падеж ед. числа).

Answer (score 2):

Из словаря Резниченко (2004 год)

Нормативное ударение **в свободных сочетаниях** падает на окончание: *две сторонЫ, четыре сторонЫ.*

Исключения относятся к разговорной или стихотворной речи или к **устойчивым оборотам**.

В частности, нормативны оба варианта: *на все четыре стОроны (сторонЫ) и по обе стОроны (сторонЫ).*

**А как быть с медалями?**

Две сторонЫ (стОроны) одной медали.  У этой медали есть две сторонЫ.

Возможно,  в устойчивом сочетании используются два варианта, а в свободном — только один.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, правильно говорить *две сторон**ы**.* Эта форма восходит к двойственному числу. Но последнее время, к сожалению, есть тенденция передвигать ударение на первый слог. Поэтому в московском метро приходится постоянно слушать объявление про *обе ст**о**роны эскалатора* (не помню слов).

Comment: Вопрос про "обе" был бы интереснее: похоже, что ударение разное для предложных и беспредложных случаев общего для всего сочетания винительного падежа ("наука" не различает эти случаи и допускает оба варианта, с тотальным уклоном на ударение в окончании). Обе сторон**ы́** (род. падеж. ед. ч.) медали имеют чеканку. Штрафу подвергли обе сторон**ы́** (род. падеж. ед. ч.) судебного процесса. По обе сто́роны (вин. падеж мн. числа) медаль покрыта золотом.

Comment: А вот почему нельзя сказать "по обе стороны́" (родительный вместо винительного)?

Comment: Можно (формально оба варианта допустимы).

Comment: Мне как-то винительный не  близок в нашем случае...

Comment: В этом https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=datnAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA396&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=QqFii12bmk&sig=ACfU3U0WqyIWKdOZ6xwX4Wmr0W4MXyTDHQ&w=1280 и других попавшихся словарях вариант "по обе стОроны" приводится первым.

Comment: Да, действительно...

Answer (score -1):

Понесут ее
Ветры буйные
Во все стороны
Света белого.

[А. В. Кольцов. Урожай (1835)]

Ударение тяготеет к первому слогу корня, если имеется смысловая параллель со словом «простОр», когда речь идет о свободе перемещения в пространстве. В этих случаях произносят: «юг и север - стОроны света», «раздаться в стОроны», «правая и левая стОроны эскалатора», «отпустить на все четыре стОроны», «руки в стОроны!».

Но! Если кого-то вытеснять, ущемлять, ограничивать в пространстве, то: «родная сторОнка», «окружать/теснить со всех сторОн», «(по)сторОнний», «любая из сторОн предмета», «одна сторонА проблемы», «взгляд со сторонЫ», «две сторонЫ одной медали», «мое дело сторонА», «смотреть по сторонАм», "ну-ка посторонИсь!».

Comment: Для перехода на новую строку достаточно набрать два пробела.

Comment: Спасибо за совет.